# Canon 60D Live View mode Not taking picture

Tags: canon, live-view

I have looked through some articles on how to shoot in live view mode on 60D. Sometime when I try to focus on a specific point (by moving the focus rectangle on the screen to that point and press the trigger half wat), the dot will blink in red and will not take any pictures. Most articles that I found only teach you how to focus on either one of the 9 points but didn't mention anything about this issue. My guess is the camera doesn't have enough light to focus on that point (But this happens under daylight). Waht's the cause and is it possible to work around this?

Comment: What happens if you set the focus switch on the lens to Manual focus? Does it take a picture in live view mode then? Also, what happens if you have the lens focus switch set to auto focus, and then change the focus rectangle, but try taking a photo when not in Live View?

Answer (score 1):

Live view mode uses contrast detection to achieve focus. This means that if you try and focus on an area with low contrast, it can have trouble focusing. You can either switch to manual focusing (and zoom the LCD view to help achieve sharp focus), or move the point to an area with good contrast (ie an area with a dark area next to a light area).